# How to use images from sharp module in React and Webpack project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sharp

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-sun-5il46?file=/src/pages/Home.js) I would like the image in it to be processed by the [sharp module](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-sun-5il46?file=/src/pages/Home.js). I want it to do this because I want this module to web optimize all the images in my React project, and to convert them to webm.

Here's the same [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-sun-5il46?file=/src/pages/Home.js) where I attempt to use ImageSharp

Comment: Thanks for your complete question alongside sandbox, I upvoted you.

Comment: When I open you codesandbox link I get this error "Could not find module in path: '' relative to '/package.json'", this is what are you trying to fix?

Comment: @lissettdm The second sandbox won't work because of the line `'../../react-logo.png?{"outputs":[{"width": 500}]}';` this is how sharp reads images from what I've read though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a convert.js in root directory to do the file conversion. check sharp [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp).

Then in package.json simply add 'node convert' before any script which needs image conversion specially start and build

```json
    "start": "node convert && react-scripts start",
    "build": "node convert && react-scripts build",
```

Now any time you start local server or build your app, it first converts the images and then does the rest.

Here is a simple example where convert.js only converts a file named 1.jpeg to output.webp with dimension 320x240.
It's all up to you how you like to organize image sizes, folders and files in project so that covert.js can find them and properly convert them.

```js
const sharp = require('sharp');
sharp('1.jpeg')
    .resize(320, 240)
    .toFile('output.webp', (err, info) => { });
```

Comment: There's no `convert.js` example in that link

Comment: Where do the images get saved to?

Comment: In the above example , original and converted images are in root directory

Answer (score 5):

You will need to make some changes:

**Webpack.config.js**

1. Move `sharp-loader` to `rules`:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg|tiff)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: "sharp-loader",
        query: {
          name: "[name].[hash:8].[ext]",
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: {
            // Preset 1
            thumbnail: {
              format: ["webp", "jpeg"],
              width: 200,
              quality: 60
            },
            // Preset 2
            prefetch: {
              // Format-specific options can be specified like this:
              format: { id: "jpeg", quality: 30 },
              mode: "cover",
              blur: 100,
              inline: true,
              size: 50
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    ...
  },
  plugins: [
    ...
  ]
};
```

If you are using **Webpack 5**:

> Rule.query is deprecated in favor of Rule.options and
> UseEntry.options.

**Home.js**

1. The `sharp-loader` will transform logo into an array of one object because of this `"outputs":[{"width": 500}]`. You will need to use the corresponding object:

```
import React from "react";
import logo from '../../react-logo.png?{"outputs":[{"width": 500}]}';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <img src={logo[0].url} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you are using `require.context` it works the same way:

```
import React from "react";

function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().reduce((curr, key) => ((curr[key] = r(key)), curr), {});
}

const images = importAll(require.context('./images/?{"outputs":[{"width": 200}, {"width": 150}]}', true, /\.png$/));


export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <img src={images['./react-logo.png'][0].url} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I get this when I do that `Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[2] has an unknown property 'query'. These properties are valid:`

Comment: Hi @Sam what version of Webpack are you using?

Comment: This is a fantastic solution! Any idea how one could import multiple images and do the same thing? Say for an image gallery with thumbnails?
e.g `importAll(require.context('../../photos', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));`

Comment: Also - any guidance on getting this to work with webpack 5?

Comment: @mortware I added an example using require.context. If you are using Webpack 5 just replace the property query with options.